# Claim money from unused health insurance (set by employer)

Tags: united-kingdom, health-insurance, business

Is it possible to claim unused health insurance money after you leave a company? It is basically unused group health in the United Kingdom (England).

The health insurance was set by the employer where both sides (employer and employee) contributed towards it.

Comment: Do you mean a Health Savings account (HSA), or a Health Flexible Spending Account (FSA), or literally the "insurance"?

Comment: @DStanley It is described as "Private medical insurance" in the contract. AXA is the company.

Comment: What is "unused health insurance money"?  (That term is unfamiliar in the US.)

Comment: @RonJohn No claims have been made.

Comment: Are you referring to premiums you paid?

Comment: @RonJohn No. The company was offering a private medical healthcare with AXA.

Comment: So what's to claim?  (The way insurance works is that everyone pays a premium, and only the sick, broken, etc get money.  If you (or your car) never break, you don't get any money.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless there's something very out of the ordinary about your specific situation, private medical insurance policies in the UK, whether group policies through a company or personal ones, are just that: insurance.

You and/or your employer pays for cover, and if you need something that the policy covers, the insurance company pays for it. There's no refund available for "unused money" because you've received the insurance you paid for.